# How to list all the classes on the class path that implements a given set of interfaces

Tags: java, spring, ide

Most IDEs allows you to do this easily for a single interface, but I am looking for classes that implements two interfaces at the same time. Is there anyway to automatically do this (without having to manually open every implementer and check)?

If no IDE supports, does Spring have such feature. (I know I can get a list of beans implementing a specific interface, but I am not sure if I can do it for all classes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly [org.reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) has what you need - unless I still misunderstand your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

from System.properties you will get the classpath.

TRY use TRY,  to open it like a zip. (Inflater or Deflater stream) you will have the class

load the class with a classloader

use instanceof xInterface && instance of yInterface

upvote if it helped :)

Comment: Classpath may contain folders - in fact, you simply be better to use a customised `URLClassloader`, adding each element from the classpath directly, rather then go through the hassle of using the zip API

Comment: I have code that does class path scanning, but I'd rather use some more interactive solution.

Comment: @billc.cn "How to list all the classes on the classpath" and "I have code that does class path scanning, but I'd rather use some more interactive solution" => good luck!

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my requirements clear. I want to find a way to do this statically in the IDE if possible. Starting the application to do the class path scanning is a bit heavy weight.